# Help with incomplete Tracking Extract documentation

Tags: marketing-cloud, documentation, data-extract, tracking-extract

Would anyone out there be able to provide some additional documentation for these **Include Options** for a **Data Extract of Tracking Data**?

I've requested an update to the one wiki page that has most of the information: [**Using Tracking Extracts**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/data_extract_activity/extract_types/tracking_extract/using_tracking_extracts/), but for now, I'm trying to piece it together.

EDIT: New Automation Studio Activities section: [**Extract Types Reference**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/use_a_data_extract_activity/extract_types_reference/)

Here's what I have so far.  The option values used in creating the Tracking Data Extract via SOAP API is in parentheses:

- **Include All List Members** (*IncludeAllListMembers*):  Include all list members in the tracking extract. If unchecked, the extract only includes list members with activity during the specified period of time.
- **Include All Subscribers** (*IncludeAllSubscribers*):  Include all subscribers in the Subscribers file of the tracking extract.  If unchecked, the extract only includes subscribers with activity corresponding to the events you select to include in the extract.
- **Include Campaign ID** ():  Include the Campaign ID of the campaign each subscriber is part of.
- **Include GEO** (): Include information like IP Address, Region, Country, City, Latitude, Longitude, Metrocode, Areacode.
- **Include Inferred Opens** (*IncludeInferredOpens*):  Include all inferred opens, or clicks on an email without a recorded open.  If unchecked, the extract only includes specific opens where the email was clicked and rendered.
- **Include Milliseconds** (*IncludeMilliseconds*): Include timestamps that display time up to the millisecond
- **Include Test Sends** (*IncludeTestSends*): Include test sends in send totals.
- **Include Unique Clicks** (*IncludeUniqueClicks*): Includes a count of the first time a single subscriber clicks any link in an email. If the same subscriber returns to the email and clicks again, that does not count as a unique click. This measures how many people clicked within the email as opposed to how many total clicks occurred.
- **Include Unique For URL Clicks** (*IncludeUniqueForURLClicks*): Include a count of the first time each link within an email is clicked. If there are three separate URLs included in the email, a single subscriber could have up to three separate unique clicks.
- **Include Unique Opens** (*IncludeUniqueOpens*): Unique opens count the first time a single subscriber opens an email, measuring how many unique subscribers opened the email.
- **Include Unsub Reason** (*IncludeUnsubReason*):  Include the user-specified Unsubscribe Reason, including custom Unsubscribe Reasons if applicable.
- **Include User Agent Information** (*IncludeUserAgentInformation*):  Include user agent data related to the open and/or click, for example, Operating System, Email Client, Browser, or Device information.
- **Send IDs** (*SendIDs*):  A comma-delimited list of SendIDs from which to filter the tracking extract. If you specify the external key of an email send definition in the extract as well, the extract will include information from all SendIDs and the email send definition.
- **Text Qualifier** (*TextQualifier*):  Surround all text with double quotation marks. Existing double quotes in the tracking extract are replaced by two single quotation marks.
- **Timezone** ():
- **unicode Output** (*UnicodeOutput*):
- **Use Local TZ in Query** (): The time zone selected in the tracking extract, determines the time zone that will be displayed in the EventDate. When the TZ checkbox is not checked, the query will pull the data from midnight to midnight server time, which uses CST (no daylight savings). If the "Use Local TZ in Query" then the data pulled will be pulled midnight to midnight based on the time zone of the account.

I'm specifically looking for insight on the difference between the *Include Unique Clicks* and *Include Unique For URL Clicks* options.

**UPDATE 2016-09-21**: I opened a case with SFMC Support.

**UPDATE 2016-09-23**: The documentation folks are waiting for information from a [**SME**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject-matter_expert).  Once they hear back, they'll update the page.

**UPDATE 2016-09-28**: Documentation team still waiting on word from SME.

**UPDATE 2016-11-08**: I've re-opened the support case and escalated through my Partner rep.  Waiting an an internal resource.

**UPDATE 2016-12-12**: Per support, the documentation updates will be published on 12/15/2016.

**UPDATE 2016-12-20**: From SFMC support:

> ...it appears that the document has updated and it is going through
> the review process. I was told that if there are no major corrections
> that need to be made to the document, it should be published within
> the next couple of days...

**UPDATE 2016-12-20 #2**: They've finally updated the documentation! I've updated it above. They did not include definitions for GEO and the two timezone options, however. :(

**UPDATE 2016-12-21**: SFMC Support is working to get the GEO and timezone entries updated on the page.  In the meantime, those values have been updated above.

**UPDATE 2016-12-22**: SFMC Support has updated the Automation Studio page relating to the Extracts, but not the original page that I requested.

Comment: This could just be me being dumb (its Monday and my brain is still trying to get back in the swing of things), but do you mean you are looking for documentation/references on the difference between Include Unique Clicks and Include Unique For URL Clicks, or just an explanation of what they are? or something completely different and I just totally misunderstood...

Comment: I'm looking for a technical explanation for those two options in particular.  What I've always understood those to mean doesn't jive with the tracking data I'm seeing.  It _should_ be fully documented on the wiki, but it's not.  ::sigh::  I'm also kinda fishing for some of the SFMC peeps to just look it up in their own internal docs.

Comment: I'm speechless about your response from SFMC Support :-O

Comment: Yeah, I decided to have a go at it as well and was told the page you referenced is "...the same documentation that our Services team works off." which is honestly pretty scary!

Comment: lolol. so typical.

Comment: Any updates here? :) Would love to know how it ends :)

Comment: Looks the same to me.  There's still parts of the Tracking Extract documentation that are only in the old (Interactions) and not in the new (Activities) and neither are complete, IMO.

Comment: Wondering if anyone can provide information on what gets included if you select "Extract Multiple Data Extension List Data"?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is all there in the name of those two fields.

*Unique Clicks* are uniqueness across everything. So if I click three different links in the email, I'm counted once under this.

*Unique Clicks for URL* are uniqueness across that one URL, even if it appears multiple times in the email. So if I click three links, two of which are the same URL, I'm counted twice under this.

Comment: Which is how I understood it, but I have a specific example of tracking extract data that surprisingly doesn't follow it.

Comment: Can you illustrate the example? Provide the data?