# Tracking Extract or Data View export?

Tags: marketing-cloud, tracking-extract, data-views

The goal is to consume tracking data (sent, open, clicks, jobs, etc.) to an external to the Marketing Cloud database. Are there any general opinions of whether it's "better" to use tracking extracts vs. setting up an automation that pulls data from _DataViews?

_DataViews seem better documented (better supported?) and have attributes not present in tracking extracts. On the other hand, tracking extracts are easier to set up.

Answer (score 0):

I typically use Tracking Extracts for applications like this.

It's nice that you can extract any date range with Tracking Extracts -- like back to MID inception.  That's not possible with the data views.

Dealing with the zip files and the non-unique file names is kind of a pain, but overall I find extracts of large amounts of data to be pretty fast.

You're right about the documentation.  [**I have issues**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/141129/help-with-incomplete-tracking-extract-documentation) with the lack of details with Tracking Extracts specifically.  The Tracking Extract page and the documentation is so bad.

Comment: I wonder if your answer has changed since Oct 2016? It seems like tracking data is not updated as often as Data Views. For example, I was frustrated to see that EmailID was not included in Send Jobs (Tracking Extract) vs. Jobs (DataView)