# Distinguishing test sends in Tracking Extract?

Tags: marketing-cloud, tracking-extract

I see that Tracking Extracts allow you to "Include Test Sends" but the data doesn't make it possible to distinguish test sends vs. non-test sends. Am I missing something? Will I have to include this as part of me send logging?

Answer (score 0):

Well, because the [**Tracking Data Extract documentation is such a clusterbleep**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/141129/help-with-incomplete-tracking-extract-documentation), who knows?

If you use the System Data Views, there's a flag that distinguishes test sends, but from what I can tell, they're either included or not based on the checkbox.

Comment: The response from support was to create two extracts, one with test sends included and one without. The missing data in the second extract would show you which were from test sends. *sigh*

Comment: Sounds about right. :|